# Separate a list into four parts based on percentage even if the list is not divisible by 10. Python

Tags: python, math, python-2.7

So I'm working with a list of an unknown length. I need to take this list and split it into four parts.

part one = first 20% of the list

part two = from 20% to 40% of the list

part three = from 40% to 80% of the list

part four = from 80% to 100% of the list.

**Now the problem with this is that if the list has less than 10 elements some of my lists will be empty. My question is how do I avoid this issue.**

This is the script I have now:

```
x = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"]

twentyPercentOne = len(x) * 0.2

twentyPercentTwo = len(x) * 0.4

fourtyPercentThree = len(x) * 0.8

i = 0
j = 2

m = []
while j < (twentyPercentOne + 1):
    m.append(x[i:j])
    i = (i + 2)
    j = (j + 2)

h = []  
while j < (twentyPercentTwo + 1):
    h.append(x[i:j])
    i = (i + 2)
    j = (j + 2)

l = []        
while j < (fourtyPercentThree + 1):
    l.append(x[i:j])
    i = (i + 2)
    j = (j + 2)

t = x[i:len(x)]
```

Output:

```
[['one', 'two']]
[['three', 'four']]
[['five', 'six'], ['seven', 'eight']]
['nine', 'ten']
```

Output if the list is less than 10 in lenght: 
    x = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven"]

```
[['one', 'two']]
[]
[['three', 'four'], ['five', 'six']]
['seven']
```

Does anybody know how to do this? I know its more of a math problem than a python problem but I have no idea how to do it and have been working on it for days. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should be the right way, for any number of splits (not just four) of any size (as long as they add up to 1):

```
def percentage_split(seq, percentages):
   assert sum(percentages) == 1.0
   prv = 0
   size = len(seq)
   cum_percentage = 0
   for p in percentages:
       cum_percentage += p
       nxt = int(cum_percentage * size)
       yield seq[prv:nxt]
       prv = nxt
```

(that's a generator function, you can get your list of quartiles like this:

```
list(percentage_split(x, [0.25]*4))
```

)

if you have numpy installed it can be a little bit terser:

```
from numpy import cumsum

def percentage_split(seq, percentages):
    cdf = cumsum(percentages)
    assert cdf[-1] == 1.0
    stops = map(int, cdf * len(seq))
    return [seq[a:b] for a, b in zip([0]+stops, stops)]
```

and if you just want the four equal quartiles...

```
numpy.split(seq, 4)
```

Comment: Sadly I don't have numpy installed. I don't understand your percentage_split function. It doesn't return anything and I can't figure out how to return what I should return to get the splits I need...

Comment: You should install and learn numpy, it is really useful. The first function is a generator function, if you want to do any serious (or fun, easy and efficient) Python programming you should learn about them too http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/ http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-pycon/index.html

Comment: I would love to do that (and might do it at home at some point) but I'm doing this on a system that uses python 2.7 and cannot be changed in any way :(

Comment: you are welcome! and try to talk with your admin to get numpy installed! ;)

Comment: Can I use `(cdf * len(seq)).astype(int)` instead of `map`?

Answer (score 0):

It should be clear to you, that it is not possible to divide a list this way with matching lengths. But here is another way:

```
def do_split(x, percent):
    L = len(x)
    idx1 = [0] + list(int(L * p) for p in percent[:-1])
    idx2 = idx1[1:] + [L]
    return list(x[i1:i2] for i1,i2 in zip(idx1, idx2))

splits = [0.2, 0.4, 0.8, 1.0]
print do_split(["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"], splits)
# ---> [['one', 'two'], ['three', 'four'], ['five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight'], ['nine', 'ten']]
print do_split( ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven"], splits)
# --> [['one'], ['two'], ['three', 'four', 'five'], ['six', 'seven']]
```